# Not able to select a checkbox in Selenium Webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to select a checkbox but I'm not able to and didn't find any solution in other threads.

Here is my HTML code for drop down list:
[image]

code:
@FindBy(css="input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched")
WebElement chrgAllocFee;

chrgAllocFee.click();

but it is not working where as other checkboxes are working when I define and use in same way. I found that the difference as compared to others is that here html code has additional line with

Please suggest how to define so that it can be recognised.

**Error getting:**
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)

Comment: shouldn't it be `@FindBy(css="input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched")`?

Comment: My mistake, there are 2 classes.I cpoied first one.@FindBy(css="input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched") WebElement chrgAllocFee;  Error: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)

Comment: This might be not related but why aren't you using id to find the element?

Comment: Also you might have to introduce wait/timeout so that selenium can detect the element's presence

Comment: It's not a dynamic element

Comment: Add a wait... what happens? Is this in an `IFRAME`?

Comment: Umm. Even if its not a dynamic element it still might have some loading issues if the code is dependent on some sort of server processing. Again why isn't id being used to get the element and have you tried introducing a wait until the element is clickable kind of code?

Comment: I tried wait as well but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:
I used javascript for clicking that field and it works fine and here is the code:

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", CamWizOR.chrgAllocFee);

CamWizOR.chrgAllocFee -> WebElement name

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='ChargeAllocationFee' and @type='checkbox']")

WebElement chrgAllocFee;

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-touched[name='ChargeAllocationFee']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched' and @name='ChargeAllocationFee']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: still getting same error..though I've found that now class name changed <div class="form-group">
  <label>Charge Allocation Fee?</label>
 <input name="ChargeAllocationFee" type="checkbox" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">                                                            </div>                   though I changed name still not able to click with above solution as you mentioned.